# Extjs4.2.1 - Load json to treepanel fails

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I create a treepanel and I and create `store` like

```
          var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            autoload: false,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'results'                 
                }
            }
          });
```

my server print json look like

```
{ "results": 
    [
    { id : '1' , text : '1', expanded: true, 
        children :[
            { id : '5' , text : '5', leaf:true},
            { id : '6' , text : '6', leaf:true}
        ]
    },
    { id : '2' , text : '2', leaf:true},
    { id : '3' , text : '3', leaf:true},
    { id : '4' , text : '4', leaf:true},
    { id : '7' , text : '7', leaf:true},
    { id : '8' , text : '8', leaf:true},
    { id : '9' , text : '9', leaf:true},
    { id : '10' , text : '10', expanded: true, 
        children :[
            { id : '11' , text : '11', leaf:true},
            { id : '12' , text : '12', leaf:true}
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

But when i run my code, i see firebug and that always run `GET http://localhost/example/data.php...` never stop :(

and my tree is added so much double

How to fix that thank

**Edit**

In real i define my treepanel with alias and using it as `xtype` 

But i create new example and get same problem.
Here is my js

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            autoload: false,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'results'                 
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            title: 'Simple Tree',
            width: 200,
            height: 150,
            store: store,
            rootVisible: false,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
```

And here is my `data.php`

```
echo "
{
    'success': true, 
    'variable': 100, 
    'results': 
    [
    { id : '1' , text : '1', expanded: true, 
        children :[
            { id : '5' , text : '5', leaf:true},
            { id : '6' , text : '6', leaf:true}
        ]
    },
    { id : '2' , text : '2', leaf:true},
    { id : '3' , text : '3', leaf:true},
    { id : '4' , text : '4', leaf:true},
    { id : '7' , text : '7', leaf:true},
    { id : '8' , text : '8', leaf:true},
    { id : '9' , text : '9', leaf:true},
    { id : '10' , text : '10', expanded: true, 
        children :[
            { id : '11' , text : '11', leaf:true},
            { id : '12' , text : '12', leaf:true}
        ]
    }
    ]
}";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have here is something I consider to be a bug in the treestore.  When you change the reader to use a root that isn't `children`, you also need to change every instance of the children property name in the data to the new name too.  That means if you want to change the root to `results`, your tree data would actually have to look something like this:

```
echo "
{
    'success': true, 
    'variable': 100, 
    'results': 
    [
    { 'id' : '1' , 'text' : '1', 'expanded': true, 
        'results':[
            { 'id' : '5' , 'text' : '5', 'leaf':true},
            { 'id' : '6' , 'text' : '6', 'leaf':true}
        ]
    },
    { 'id' : '2' , 'text' : '2', 'leaf':true},
    { 'id' : '3' , 'text' : '3', 'leaf':true},
    { 'id' : '4' , 'text' : '4', 'leaf':true},
    { 'id' : '7' , 'text' : '7', 'leaf':true},
    { 'id' : '8' , 'text' : '8', 'leaf':true},
    { 'id' : '9' , 'text' : '9', 'leaf':true},
    { 'id' : '10' , 'text' : '10', 'expanded': true, 
        'results':[
            { 'id' : '11' , 'text' : '11', 'leaf':true},
            { 'id' : '12' , 'text' : '12', 'leaf':true}
        ]
    }
    ]
}";
```

The other option is to change the top level `results` property name to `children` and mark the root of your store as `children`.

Comment: It took me a while to figure this one out originally because the behavior doesn't make sense.  We use a ton of trees in our app.

Answer (score 1):

check your autoLoad config spelling.

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        //    autoload: false,
            autoLoad : false,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'results'                 
                }
            }
          });
```

Comment: i just change it and get the same problem :(

Comment: can you provide treepanel  configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add root data to store like follow

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            autoLoad : false,
            root: {
                text: 'Corporate Media',
                id: '0',
                expanded: true
            }
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'results'                 
                }
            }
          });
```

Comment: can you create example on jsfiddle using your code. I'll check it.

Comment: but that using php and jsfiddle i think that can't. I'm using extjs 4.2.1.883, I will edit my title