# ExtJS 4 Tree Store Load remote data and work with it locally

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm define my tree store as:

```
Ext.define('Portal.store.GroupsTreeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'Portal.model.GroupTreeModel',

    autoLoad: false,

    proxy: {
        method: 'get',
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'groups/get',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            messageProperty: 'message',
            root: 'data'
        }
    },
    // Prevent auto loading
        root: {
        expanded: true,
        text: "",
        "data": []
    }
});
```

my model as:

```
Ext.define('Portal.model.GroupTreeModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'type', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

I recieve JSON data like:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "ok",
    "data": [{
        "name": "group1",
        "type": "group",
        "expanded": true,
        "children": [{
            "name": "admin_2503",
            "type": "people",
            "leaf": true
        },
        {
            "name": "u1",
            "type": "people",
            "leaf": true
        },
        {
            "name": "u2",
            "type": "people",
            "leaf": true
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "group2",
        "type": "group",
        "expanded": false,
        "leaf": false,
        "children": [{
            "name": "u5",
            "type": "people",
            "leaf": true
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to load all my tree store data at once and after work with it locally (e.g. search, filter and so on), but with this store config all nodes shows unexpanded and on expand action perform query to provided `url: groups\get` with node id, recieve the same JSON and add `group1` and `group2` as node child's. How should I configure my store for this purpose?

**UPDATE** Definition of view:

```
Ext.define('Portal.view.GroupsTree', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',

store: 'GroupsTreeStore',

border: false,
emptyText: 'No records found',
multiSelect: false,
rootVisible: false,

columns: [
    {
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 1,
        sortable: true,
        text: 'Name'
    }
],

initComponent: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

Comment: Definition of the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the answer to this link, it is probably causing what you are experiencing.  [Extjs4.2.1 - Load json to treepanel fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931443/extjs4-2-1-load-json-to-treepanel-fails/18960896#18960896)

Comment: Thx alot! It's fixed my issue! Strange behavior: I always thought that `proxy reader root` attribute specifies a data container and has nothing to do with the format of the data.